# Как в PHP сжать (минимизировать) перед отправкой клиенту буферезированный html-контент?

Tags: php, compression

Отдаю клиенту контент из вьюшки:

```
ob_start();
include "app/views/$view.php";
exit(ob_get_clean());
```

Во `$view.php` могут быть пробелы, комментарии `\r\n`-ы и прочее ненужное для нормального парсинга контента клиентом. Как вычистить лишнее из буфера или перед его формированием?

Comment: если это для скорости, то ничего не нужно делать. А если для кросоты, то желаю удачи

Comment: Вы заблуждаетесь, пробельные символы могут повлиять на отображение страницы, по умолчанию они отображаются как один пробел, а со стилем `white-space: pre-wrap` все пробельные символы отображаются целиком как есть, а комментарии теоретически могут парситься скриптами. Если вы хотите убрать лишние пробельные символы — убирайте их самостоятельно из `$view.php`. Но как правильно заметили выше, в этом в принципе нет смысла

Comment: тогда уж gzip для ответа настройте, а не пытайтесь убирать. Если бы юзали шаблонизаторы а-ля smarty, то там лишнее можно удалить на этапе компиляции шаблона. Пытаться удалять что-то из сформированного html приведет вас к большим косякам.